# How do I change a column name in MySQL5

Tags: mysql

I have this so far but the Column 'name' is ambiguous, so I want to change the name column in the modle table to something else (There is also a name column is the student table). How can I do this?

```
SELECT name
FROM student
JOIN modle ON modle.id = event.modle
JOIN event ON event.id = attends.event
JOIN attends ON attends.student = student.id
WHERE name LIKE '%Database%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases allow you to create your own column names for a particular resultset.
Example:

```
SELECT modle.`name` AS model_name, student.`name` AS student_name
FROM student
JOIN modle ON modle.id = event.modle
JOIN event ON event.id = attends.event
JOIN attends ON attends.student = student.id
WHERE name LIKE '%Database%';
```

---

If you want to permanently change a column name use the `ALTER TABLE` command:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE student 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` student_name VARCHAR(50);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Does this statement go after the FROM statement, and in your example what it is exactly changing the name to?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` statement is its own statement, independent of the `SELECT` statement. In this example it changes the name of the column from `name` to `student_name`.

Comment: One more thing, why do you add the VARCHAR(50); because it seems to no be working

Comment: That was simply an example since I do not know your table definition. You want to place there the actual definition of that column. For example if it was an integer column the command would be `ALTER TABLE example_table CHANGE COLUMN x y INTEGER;`

Comment: We have a large PHP code base that uses the current column name. Is there a way to give the same column two names at the same time? I would like to be able to have two  queries like this `SELECT * from myTable where old_col_name = 4` and at the same time `SELECT * from myTable where new_col_name = 4`. Both names `old_col_name` and `new_col_name` must point to the same column. Is this possible? This way we could write the new php-code using the new name but the old code would still run using the old column-name.

Comment: @surfmuggle: yes, you can have multiple aliases for the same column. hopefully i've understood your question, correctly.

Comment: Sorry for beeing not clear enough. I wonder how we can move from the current bad names to better names; this applies to column-names as well as table names. I assume we could create a view for each table. Two options create a view with the better name and new code calls the view. Old code still uses the old table names. Gradually replace old code with new code. Or create view with oldname, rename table: old code uses bad view name, new code uses the improved new tablename. Gradually replace old code untill views are no longer needed.

Comment: I agree with the view-based approach. I've seen production databases which, for read-only stuff, were operating exclusively on views for a variety of reasons including flexibility and data integrity.

Comment: Just to clarify: my hope was that a column `C` in a table `T` can have two names at the same time: `CREATE TABLE T (C       varchar(10));` and instead of renaming `ALTER TABLE T RENAME COLUMN C TO D;` i would like give C a second name like this `ALTER TABLE T ADD_ALIAS  COLUMN C SECONDName D;`. This way we could start using the new names in new code instead of creating views for the new code.

Comment: and just to clarify what i'm getting at: views would address this for any future migrations, right? because i'm guessing this isn't the first, nor would it be the last time something like this would happen. i'm not aware of any RDBMS using anything like `ADD_ALIAS`.

Comment: @surfmuggle: keeping a codebase and database in sync over changes aka "database migrations" are not a simple concept. i suggest it's not an ideal use of time to discuss alternative ways of doing this that don't even exist -- that i know of -- within the comments of a SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the column with the table to avoid ambiguity as well as provide aliases.

For example:

```
SELECT modle.name, student.name AS student_name FROM …
```

However, I advocate changing the column name in this case since `name` is a reserved word in some SQL flavors.

You could do so with an [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command or your database manager.

```
ALTER TABLE modle CHANGE COLUMN name modle_name [column_definition]
```

Comment: +1. Beat me by several minutes :D I already had the answer written so I thought I'd post. Don't mean to step on your toes. Cheers.

Comment: No worries. You provided a much longer example. Like the HRs too. I'll have to adopt that format :)